# How to deploy a different host.json for a different deployment profile?

Tags: azure, environment-variables, azure-functions

I deploy my Azure Function from Visual Studio, and as part of my Functions project I have a host.json file which specifies some settings which I need to change for Production vs Development.  (Specifically, the extensions:queues:batchSize setting).  The reason is unfortunately largely beyond my control (the database I use in development is lower-tier than the production one and higher batch sizes will cause it to fall over pretty quickly).

I'd like to be able to specify a small batch size for development and higher batch size for production.  I have production and development deployment profiles already, but I don't see any way to vary the host.json file.

Is there 1) a way to do this natively, and/or 2) a better DevOps practice I should be using to make this issue obsolete?  I can't use Azure DevOps yet (long story) but perhaps just having separate branches for dev and production would be sufficient?

Comment: IMO, if you don't want to create two projects and deploy them to different Function app/slots, separate branches and build pipelines seem the only way.

Comment: you can just inject the desired value in the host,json file in your release pipeline using a powershell task

Comment: @Thomas This relies on Azure DevOps, I assume?

Comment: Yes, it works using azure devops or any CI/Cd tool

Comment: @Thomas but how would I be able to access the host.json file from the build artifact zip?

Comment: somehow you will have to unzip it, open the file, change the setting and rezip it before uploading it.

Answer (score 4):

Another way to do this would be to set environment variables for it. In your case, you could set `extensions:queues:batchSize` with one like this

```
AzureFunctionsJobHost__extensions__queues__batchSize
```

When deploying to azure, this would be an application setting with this name/key